# React Native lifecycle issue on back navigation

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-router, lifecycle

I am a newbie in React Native.
I have developed a common drawer and navigation bar using following.
**Main.js**

```
 var navBar;
 if(hideNavBar){
  navBar=null;
 }else{
  navBar=<Navigator.NavigationBar />
 }

 <Drawer disabled={hideDrawer}>
    <Navigator 
       navigationBar={navBar}/>
 </Drawer>
```

Here **hideNavBar** and **hideDrawer** are state of **Main.js** which I am changing in **componentWillMount()** and **componentWillUpdate()** of other components according to my need of hiding navigation bar and drawer.

**Page1.js**

```
componentWillUpdate(){
    this.props.configureDrawerNavBar(false,false);
  }

componentWillMount(){
    this.props.configureDrawerNavBar(false,false);
  }
```

here **configureDrawerNavBar(hideDrawer, hideNavBar)** is a function in **Main.js** responsible for changing the state of it and I am passing this function as a props to other components.

Everything is working fine. But while back navigation there is delay in hiding or showing navigation bar which is easily noticeable.

**What I observed :** while navigating back, **before any methods of lifecycle of component** the **Page2** goes away and I can see the **Page1** on the screen  and **after the whole lifecycle methods of component of Page1 and the Main.js** the navbar is getting updated *(i.e show/hide according to state)* as it is common for all pages placed in the **Main.js** which is at the parent level of hierarchy.

***The problem is obvious according to my code but I am not getting the trick to solve it.
Any help or any other work around to achieve my goal would be greatly appreciated.***